# Adding html text to a H.map.DomMarker

Tags: javascript, here-api

I want to add text to a marker. I have a variable with an attribute "text" that I want to appear in the Marker, when it appears on the map.

```
 var baseLat = baseLocation.lat;
 var baseLng = baseLocation.lng;
 var basePoint = new H.geo.IPoint( baseLat , baseLng );

 var baseMarker = new H.map.DomMarker( basePoint );
 var markerHTML = '<div class="px_marker">' +  baseLocation.text + '</div>';
 baseMarker.setZIndex(1);
 baseMarker.setData(markerHTML);
 domGroup.addObject(baseMarker);
```

baseLocation.text = "test"

I would expect a marker with the word "test"

Answer (score 0):

While creating map object, you can specify the coordinates and icon both as parameters, and in icon, you can embed both the text and animation, if is required.

please refer following example which illustrates the same requirement

**developer.here.com/api-explorer/maps-js/v3.0/markers/map-with-dom-marker**

Also a little code snippnet that could help..happy coding..!!

```
<html> 
 <script>

  // Initialize the platform object:
   var platform = new H.service.Platform({
   'app_id': ‘xxxxxxxxxx’,
   'app_code': ‘yyyyyyyyyyy’
   });


// Obtain the default map types from the platform object
var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

// Instantiate (and display) a map object:
var map = new H.Map(
document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
maptypes.normal.map,
{
  zoom: 10,
  center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
});

// Define a variable holding SVG mark-up that defines an animated icon image:

 var markerHTML = '<div>' + "text" + '</div>';

 // Create an icon object, an object with geographic coordinates and a marker:

 var icon = new H.map.DomIcon(markerHTML),
 coords = {lat: -22.8906, lng: -43.2283},
 baseMarker = new H.map.DomMarker(coords, {icon: icon});

 // Set map center and zoom, add the marker to the map:
 map.setCenter(coords);
 map.setZoom(18);
 map.addObject(baseMarker);
 </script>
 </html>
```